# MongoDB "Dropping all pooled connections" error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, replication, sharding

I am using MongoDB Sharded Cluster architecture to store my datas safely and efficiently, but when I check my mongos (or mongoRouter) logs, in daily bases I have been getting this error on different times for each shards, config server and mongos regularly:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-02-28T15:59:38.533+03:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONNPOOL", "id":22572,   "ctx":"establishCursors cleanup","msg":"Dropping all pooled connections","attr":{"hostAndPort":"server1:27019","error":"ShutdownInProgress: Pool for server1:27019 has expired."}}
```

• Following figure shows my sharded cluster set-up (server1, server2 and server3 represent different servers)
[image]

• Following code block shows the client connection that I use to connect MongoDB in Python3. (I refresh the connection every 5 hours, that's why I use "five_hours_added_time" variable.)

```
class MongoRouterClient:
    __instance = None
    __connection_uptime = None

    @staticmethod
    def get_instance():
        if MongoRouterClient.__instance is None:
            MongoRouterClient()

        elif (MongoRouterClient.__connection_uptime + five_hours_added_time) < datetime.datetime.now():
            MongoRouterClient.__instance.close()
            MongoRouterClient.__instance = pymongo.MongoClient(
                f"mongodb://{MONGOROUTER1_URL},{MONGOROUTER2_URL},{MONGOROUTER3_URL}",
                connect=False,
                serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000,
                readPreference='secondaryPreferred')
            MongoRouterClient.__connection_uptime = datetime.datetime.now()
            return MongoRouterClient.__instance
        return MongoRouterClient.__instance

    def __init__(self):
        """ Virtually private constructor. """

        if MongoRouterClient.__instance is not None:
            raise Exception("This class is a singleton!")

        else:
            MongoRouterClient.__instance = pymongo.MongoClient(
                f"mongodb://{MONGOROUTER1_URL},{MONGOROUTER2_URL},{MONGOROUTER3_URL}",
                connect=False,
                serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000,
                readPreference='secondaryPreferred')
            MongoRouterClient.__connection_uptime = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Does anyone know what is the reason of getting this error and what to do for solving it?